# how to solve Facebook api permission problem

Tags: python, facebook

I'm trying to post on Facebook using Facebook graph API with python but when I try to do that I get this error message

```
    graph.put_object(group,'feed', message=message,link=link)
  File "C:\Users\ansas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\facebook\__init__.py", line 189, in put_object
    return self.request(
  File "C:\Users\ansas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\facebook\__init__.py", line 313, in request
    raise GraphAPIError(result)
facebook.GraphAPIError: (#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and \
          either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both pages_read_engagement \
          and pages_manage_posts permission with page token; If posting to a page, \
          requires both pages_read_engagement and pages_manage_posts as an admin with \
          sufficient administrative permission
```

can anyone help me solve this error? thanks in front

Comment: Did you do what the error message tells you to do?

Comment: Yes i gave the needed premisions

Comment: And the app is installed in the group. As said: "requires app being installed in the group"

Comment: i don't know how to do that

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/help/261149227954100